# How can I remove only submitted time from node view?

Tags: display-suite

I only need to remove the published time from the submitted by field while viewing the node. Is it possible to do with display suite or there are other different approaches?

[image]

Comment: create a view block of node ,select authored by field only, not authored on field,render that block into the region,by default publish date should hide from content type

Comment: I only want to remove published time, not the whole date.

Comment: Can you show the date pattern which you want to show ,by some screenshot,also mention your drupal version

Comment: @Drupallearner I am on D8 and I have uploaded the image above which is a field and currently being rendered. However, I don't want to display time just day and date.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**->create a custom date format go to **"admin/config/regional/date-time"** then click **"Add format"** link,give appropriate name, in my case i have taken name **"new custom"**, in format string input **"l,F d, Y"** then save.

**Step 2**->In your Your_theme.theme file write the preprocess function for node:

```
function Your_theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
// Getting the node creation time stamp from the node object.
  $date = $variables['node']->getCreatedTime();
// Here you can use drupal's format_date() function, or some custom PHP date formatting.
 $variables['date_custom'] = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')-
 >format($date, 'Machine_name_of_created_date_format'); //In my case machine name was "new_custom"
   }
```

**Step 3**->Create a twig template of your content type like **node--your-content-machine-name.html.twig**

replace the following line :
{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}

with

{% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date_custom }}{% endtrans %}

Comment: Amazing explanation, however, I just found out the theme hook suggestion shows the output is being rendered from field.html.twig {{ item.content }} variable from core... not from the node template. Should I implement the same process you suggested above?

Comment: yes you can try once

Answer (score 0):

for D7, not shure for D8, in your template.php file inside your theme, replace YOURTHEME with your sub-theme name, place this funcion:

```
/*
*  change "submited by"
*/
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['submitted'] = 
  t('!username ', 
    array('!username' => $vars['name']));

  $vars['date'] = 
  t('!datetime', 
    array('!datetime' => format_date($vars['node']->created, 
        'custom', 'M/d/Y')));
  }
```

for a diferent date format see: http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php